# android - TimePicker Numeric Keyboard Next Button Issue

Tags: android, keyboard, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have put two time pickers in my code and it works well. However, when someone taps a time picker to open the numeric keyboard a "Next" button appears rather than a "Done" button. When I click the "Next" button the keyboard changes from a numeric keyboard to a regular keyboard. The regular keyboard that opens cannot be dismissed.

Below is the XML for the time pickers (I can add more code if needed, but I hope this is sufficient).

```
<TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/start_text"
        android:id="@+id/time_picker_start"></TimePicker>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_time"
            android:layout_below="@id/time_picker_start"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:id="@+id/end_text"/>
        <TimePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/end_text"

            android:id="@+id/time_picker_end"></TimePicker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your TextView is not receiving the focus and this makes it to open the keyboard.

Also according you should define explicit the "action code" so it will work as design regarding the "next/Done" button.